# QueryDsl - OR statement not working

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have the following QueryDSL query:

```
    QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;

    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    builder.or(customer.person.name.containsIgnoreCase(query));
    builder.or(customer.company.name.containsIgnoreCase(query));

    return builder;
```

And I expect to get results from Persons that contains the name = query and/or Companies that contains the query parameter. But I get nothing.

This is my `Customer` class mapping:

```
@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = false, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Company company;

@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = false, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;
```

Did someone knows what I'm missing here?

I expect to get a query like this:

```
select o 
from Customer 
where o.person.name like '%:name%' or o.company.name like '%:name%'
```

This is the generated query:

```
select 
    count(customer0_.uid) as col_0_0_ 
from 
    Customer customer0_ 
cross join 
    Person person1_ 
cross join 
    Company company2_ 
where 
    customer0_.person_uid=person1_.uid 
    and customer0_.company_uid = company2_.uid 
    and (lower(person1_.name) like ? escape '!' or lower(company2_.name) like ? escape '!') limit ?
```

It uses a count because it's the first query that Spring Data use to paginate the result.

Comment: Are both company and person mandatory properties? Did you check what the SQL query looks like?

Comment: @TimoWestkämper no, they are optional... I updated the question with the generated query. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query looks ok. Most probably you get wrong results because the implicit property based joins make the joins inner joins.

Using left joins you might get the results you need.

```
QPerson person = QPerson.person;
QCompany company = QCompany.company;
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
builder.or(person.name.containsIgnoreCase(str));
builder.or(company.name.containsIgnoreCase(str));

query.from(customer)
     .leftJoin(customer.person, person)
     .leftJoin(customer.company, company)
     .where(builder);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! sadly it doesn't work. Now I realize that Person or Company may be null. I think this is affecting the query.

Comment: certainly this is affecting the query. All entities that contains the two non-nullable objects are working fine. Did you know if it is possible to workaround this issue?

Comment: Do you get the same results with my suggested query? The joins on the SQL level should at least be left joins. Could you confirm?

Comment: It the same result. I create a gist with more information:  https://gist.github.com/cavarzan/7617892 . The problem is the Customer can be a Person or a Company, never both together, so it always contain a null reference to Person or Company

Comment: My bad Timo, I'm using `builder.or(company.person.name.containsIgnoreCase(str));` intead of `builder.or(person.name.containsIgnoreCase(str));`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: in case that I want to perform a left join like builder.or(company.person.name.containsIgnoreCase(str));
In this case the query is returning 0 elements. Is any advice to use this kind of child relationship? Thanks!